# How to fetch the browser network calls response using selenium java?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-devtools, selenium4

In my application on every step the getImage API calls are generated I want to fetch the preview of that API call on every step.
I tried the below code but it gives the calls generated after launching the site.

```
public void seleniumTest() throws InterruptedException {
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        DevTools devTools = driver.getDevTools();
        devTools.createSession();
        devTools.send(Network.enable(Optional.empty(), Optional.empty(), Optional.empty()));
        devTools.addListener(Network.requestWillBeSent(), requestConsumer -> {
            Request request = requestConsumer.getRequest();
            System.out.println(request.getUrl());

        });
        devTools.addListener(Network.responseReceived(), responseConsumer -> {
            Response response = responseConsumer.getResponse();
            System.out.println(response.getStatus() + " " + response.getUrl());
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        });

        driver.get("https://stagedesigner.artifi.net//APIDesigner?personalization=d2Vic2l0ZUlkPTE0NSZ3ZWJBcGlDbGllbnRLZXk9NWFiNjczNzYtNTU1NS00YzMwLWE3ODAtNThiODQyNWE2MmY2JnByb2R1Y3RDb2RlPUFVVE8xJnVzZXJJZD11bmRlZmluZWQ");
    }
```

https://i.imgur.com/QO1eJk3.png